# Change link color on div hover

Tags: css

How do I change my link colors when I hover a div?

I tried to use:

```
#voltarTEST {
    width: 80px;
    height: 62px;
    padding-top: 16px;
    background-image: url(../img/multiLangImage/Seta11.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#seguinteBtn {
    width: 80px;
    height: 62px;
    padding-top: 16px;
    background-image: url(../img/multiLangImage/Seta21.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #777;
}
#seguinteBtn:hover {
    background-image: url(../img/multiLangImage/Seta22.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}
#voltarText {
/*  padding-right: 10px;*/
    padding-left: 30px;
}
#voltarNEText {
/*  padding-right: 10px;*/
    padding-left: 30px;
}
#voltarTEST:hover {
    background-image: url(../img/multiLangImage/Seta12.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#voltarTEST a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: x-small;
    font-family: Verdana;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999;
}
#voltarTEST a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: x-small;
    font-family: Verdana;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}
#dataUltimaSincMSG {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
#estadoSinc {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

But that did not work, this only changes color when I hover over the link.

Comment: Name of the div or plz paste the html

Comment: A jsFiddle is always handy, it directly shows what you currently have (and it is easy to change it).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Add this:

```
#voltarTEST:hover a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: x-small;
    font-family: Verdana;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, well that was a really dumb mistake LOL

Answer (score 9):

You want to set the hover event on the div, not the link..

`#voltarTEST a:hover` should be `#voltarTEST:hover a`

The first (the way you had it) says when the link inside of the `voltarTEST` div is hovered on. The second says apply this style to links inside `voltarTEST` when `voltarTEST` is hovered on.

Here's a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aG5fK/)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `:hover` on the `div` instead of the `a` :

```
#voltarTEST:hover a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: x-small;
    font-family: Verdana;

    text-decoration: none;
    color:#FFF;
}
```