# Change link color on div hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My problem is that, when I hover over my div, it doesn't change the links color to what I want it to be. It just stays its default black color.

How can I make it so that when I hover over the thumbnail-cointainer div, it changes the color of the link?

```
<div class="thumbnail-container">
    <a href="">Text Here</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #005580;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.thumbnail-container {
  width: 220px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.thumbnail-container:hover {
  color: #0088cc;
}
```

Comment: try .thumbnail-container:hover a {
  color: #0088cc;
}

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193762/change-link-color-on-div-hover

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is selector specificity. Select the anchor as well:

```
.thumbnail-container:hover,
.thumbnail-container:hover a {
  color: #0088cc;
}
```

Or depending on what you want you may use `inherit`. Just add this:

```
.thumbnail-container a {
  color:inherit;
}
```

Comment: But this changes the color of the link when you put your cursor anywhere in the container div, which is not what is typically needed. I need the link to turn blue if I hover the thumbnail, not anywhere in the container div.

Comment: It's alright, I already figured it out myself. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 4):

```
.thumbnail-container:hover a {
    color: #0088cc;
}
```