# Changing color of link on hover of a div

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, css-selectors

I'm trying to change the color of a link on hover of a `<div>`. Is that possible using just CSS? If not, how would I achieve this?

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
}
div:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href='www.google.com'> www.google.com </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change link color on div hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493763/change-link-color-on-div-hover) or [Change link color on div hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193762/change-link-color-on-div-hover)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML / CSS - Hover Link Color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458313/html-css-hover-link-color)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to style the anchor, not the div. Try this:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
}
div:hover a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href='www.google.com'> www.google.com </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

rjdown's answer is correct, but the question is if you still need the div at all.

All a div does is provide a block for you to style. If you style the anchor as block, you have just that. Code bloat is bad for your SEO and headache-freeness. ;-)

Try this:

```css
a:link {
  display: block;
  /* make it act as the div would */
  overflow: auto;
  /* or what you want, but good practice to have it */
  border: solid 1px black;
}
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<a href='www.google.com'> www.google.com </a>
```

Remember to use more than a color change on your hover or the 1 in 12 males with color blindness won't see a thing, potentially, happening. The focus and active additions are for accessibility too. Especially focus is very important for keyboard users.

Good luck.

Comment: Good point. We actually don't need the divs as we can just change the links to do the same thing as the divs would. It would be less messy, and less code. +1 for good points.

Answer (score 1):

The `div` itself has no text, so there's no place to apply the `color` property. So when you hover a div with nothing to `color`, nothing happens.

As mentioned in another answer, apply the `hover` to the anchor element, which contains text.

But your original code would work if instead of `color` you used `background-color` or `border`.

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 15px;
}

div:hover {
    color: red;                /* won't work; nothing to color */
    background-color: aqua;    /* this will work */
    border: 2px dashed #777;   /* this will work */
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href = 'www.google.com'> www.google.com </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Btw, what is the difference between using background, and background-color? I always just use background, and it seem to do the same thing as background-color.

Comment: `background-color` only sets the background color. `background` is a shorthand property for setting multiple background values. You're right, `background: black` is functionally equivalent to `background-color: black`. But with `background` you can also set `background-image`, `background-position`, etc. (A similar relationship exists between `list-style` and `list-style-type`). Learn more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Answer (score 0):

We can simply assign inherit value to all the CSS properties of anchor tag ,
Thus when you hover above its container DIV element , it will inherit all the new properties defined inside DIV:hover.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background: blue;
}

a {
  text-decoration: inherit;
  color: inherit;
}

div:hover {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
</div>
```